# Modifying one array element , changes all elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm revisiting JavaScript and messing around with classes, arrays and objects. I have a class named School with a `modifyStudent()` method which is intended to modify a `studentList` array element and only that element, but it seems that it changes all elements in the array which are empty. (The elements consist of an object with the following properties: `name`, `age`, `height`).

**Code: School class and its properties**

```
class School {
    /**
     * Settings for the school
     * @param {string} name The title of the school
     * @param {string} location The whereabouts of the school
     * @param {number} foundedIn The year the school was founded
     * @param {number} numOfStudents The number of students you wish to attend the school
     */
    constructor(name, location, foundedIn, numOfStudents) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.foundedIn = foundedIn;
        this.numOfStudents = numOfStudents;
        this.info = {
            name: this.name,
            location: this.location,
            foundedIn: this.foundedIn,
            numOfStudents: this.numOfStudents,
            studentList: [
                { name: 'Harry', age: 17, height: "5'6" },
                { name: 'Max', age: 17, height: "5'6" },
                { name: 'Tay', age: 13, height: "5'2" },
                { name: 'John', age: 14, height: "5'5" },
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

**Code: Relevant Methods**

```
modifyStudent(name, age, height, index) {
        // Checks if the parameters are empty
        if (!name || !age || !height || !index) return 'Error: Missing Arguments';
        if (typeof name != 'string' || typeof age != 'number' || typeof height != 'string' || typeof index != 'number') return 'Check the arguments are the correct primitive';
        // Checks for names have been used before
        for (let i = 0; i < this.info.studentList.length; i++) {
            let studName = this.info.studentList[i].name;
            if (studName === name) return 'This name is already on the list.';
        };
        // Identifying student via index
        let studArr = this.info.studentList[index];
        // Assigning new property values
        studArr.name = name;
        studArr.age = age;
        studArr.height = height;
        return studArr;
    }
```

```
/**
 * Fills the student list array with blank objects of student information.
 */
addVacancies() {
        let difference = this.numOfStudents - this.info.studentList.length;
        let vacancy = { name: '', age: 12, height: '' };
        for (let i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
            let arr = this.info.studentList;
            arr.push(vacancy);
        }
    }
```

**Code: Execution**

```
let teenHigh = new School('Teen High Academy', 'Houston, Texas', 2012, 20);

teenHigh.addVacancies();
console.log(teenHigh.info.studentList);
teenHigh.modifyStudent('Zak', 17, "5'11", 6);
console.log(teenHigh.info.studentList);
```

**Code: Output**

```
[
  { name: 'Harry', age: 17, height: "5'6" }, 
  { name: 'Max', age: 17, height: "5'6" },   
  { name: 'Tay', age: 13, height: "5'2" },   
  { name: 'John', age: 14, height: "5'5" },  
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' },
  { name: '', age: 12, height: '' }
]
[
  { name: 'Harry', age: 17, height: "5'6" },
  { name: 'Max', age: 17, height: "5'6" },
  { name: 'Tay', age: 13, height: "5'2" },
  { name: 'John', age: 14, height: "5'5" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" },
  { name: 'Zak', age: 17, height: "5'11" }
]
```

I would just like to know why this is happening and how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: `arr.push(vacancy)` doesn't make a copy of `vacancy`. All the array elements are references to the same object. Move `let vacancy = ...` into the loop to create distinct objects.

Comment: Could you just tell me why putting it in the for loop made it a distinct object.

Comment: Outside the loop, you just create one object and keep using it for all the array elements. Inside the loop you create a new object each time.